# tcl client is not receiving the response from python server

Tags: tcl

```
package require itcl
package require json
package require ncgi
namespace import ::itcl::*
class StaffClientWithManhattan {

    variable clientSocket
    constructor {port} {
        set host localhost
        set clientSocket [socket $host $port]
        fconfigure $clientSocket -buffering full -buffersize 4096
    }

    method send_message {message} {
        set jsonMessage [json::dict2json $message]
        set stringMessage [format "%s" $jsonMessage]
        puts "request is: $stringMessage"
        puts $clientSocket $stringMessage
        flush $clientSocket

        set replyFromServer [ncgi::decode [gets $clientSocket]]
        puts " Response from server : $replyFromServer"
        set resultInDict [json::json2dict $replyFromServer]
        puts "from server in dict format:  $resultInDict"
        close $clientSocket
        return $resultInDict
    }

    method create_component {varrequest_type varcommand varcomponent_type vardriver_path varrequest_timeout varhost varport} {
        set message [dict create request_type $varrequest_type command $varcommand params [dict create component_type $varcomponent_type driver_path $vardriver_path request_timeout $varrequest_timeout host $varhost port $varport]]
        puts "request in dictionary format: $message"
        set response [send_message $message]
        set component_id [dict get $response component_id]
        return $component_id              
    }

    method perform_action {varrequest_type varcommand varcomponent_id} {
        set message [dict create request_type $varrequest_type command $varcommand params [dict create component_id $varcomponent_id]]

        puts "Action message is: $message"
        set response [send_message $message]
        return $response
    }
}
StaffClientWithManhattan scm 9999
set component_id "[scm create_component action create_component ManhattanClient C://NodeWebKit//chromedriver2_server.exe 5 localhost 9999]"

#StaffClientWithManhattan scm 9999
#scm perform_action action find_people 1
```

In this program I am trying to connect to a Python server, server is receiving the request correctly and sending the response but my tcl client is not receiving the response. Please help me, I have tried a lot but not able to understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First off, is it *really* hanging at this line?

```
set replyFromServer [ncgi::decode [gets $clientSocket]]
```

If so, the issues are likely either that you've got the line translation wrong — with sockets, Tcl defaults to using CRLF because that's the usual right thing for network protocols — or that the server isn't flushing its output buffers. Using [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) on the client will allow you to figure out which it is; the client should be receiving the data into itself, and if not, you'll know that the real issue is with the server buffer not being flushed.

If it's a line ending translation problem, e.g., because the other end is sending just a line feed, you've got to fix your client to expect that. (Mixed up expectations cause trouble, such as waiting infinitely for a character that never comes.) That might be as simple as updating the `fconfigure` to have an extra option:

```
fconfigure $clientSocket -buffering full -buffersize 4096 -translation lf
```

It's hard to say more without knowing where the data is stuck…

Comment: Thanks Donal for your reply

Comment: Thanks Donal for your reply : your guess is right, it is the line  set replyFromServer [ncgi::decode [gets $clientSocket]] where it is stucking. Control never reaches to this line. I have tried with -transalation lf but it is still not working.

Comment: One more thing sir, when I debug the code it is terminated at the line: set response [send_message $message]  by producing error message as follows:  Execution error 206: ItclObjectCmd cannot get context object (NULL)
    while executing
"send_message $message"

Stack trace:
 #0 file:/D:/Uttam/eclpro/server-client/staffing/StaffClientWithManhattan.itcl [34]
 #1 file:/D:/Uttam/eclpro/server-client/staffing/StaffClientWithManhattan.itcl [48]